# How do I Count Field Values from a Single Row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to PHP and MySQL and am struggling with this... I am collecting form data from a PHP insert page. It is a survey questionnaire. There are 20 questions, and all the answers will either be  `A`, `B` and `C`. The table has an id column, and a column for each question (`Q1, Q2, Q3... Q20`). The data may look something like this;

```
+------+-----+
|  id  |  1  |
+------+-----+
|  Q1  |  A  |
|  Q2  |  B  |
|  Q3  |  A  |
|  .   |  .  |
|  .   |  .  |
|  .   |  .  |
|  Q20 |  C  |
+------+-----+
```

Now, what I am trying to do is to count how many values of `A`, `B` and `C` appear in a single row (with `id=1` for example).

I've found lots of ways of counting values in multiple columns, but so far have not found a way to count/group values in a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with a MySQL query:

```
select id,
  sum(case when `1` = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as CountA,
  sum(case when `1` = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as CountB,
  sum(case when `1` = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as CountC
from SurveyTable
group by id
order by id;
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d48d1/1) with limited test data.

---

**Addendum**. Carlos posted an updated structure, leading to the following answers. Hope these are close :)

This will give you one very wide row with grand totals:

```
select
  sum(case when Q1 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Q1CountA,
  sum(case when Q1 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as Q1CountB,
  sum(case when Q1 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as Q1CountC,
  sum(case when Q2 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Q2CountA,
  sum(case when Q2 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as Q2CountB,
  sum(case when Q2 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as Q2CountC,
  sum(case when Q3 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Q3CountA,
  sum(case when Q3 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as Q3CountB,
  sum(case when Q3 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as Q3CountC,
  sum(case when Q4 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Q4CountA,
  sum(case when Q4 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as Q4CountB,
  sum(case when Q4 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as Q4CountC,
  sum(case when Q5 = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as Q5CountA,
  sum(case when Q5 = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as Q5CountB,
  sum(case when Q5 = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as Q5CountC
from SurveyTable;
```

If you want to get one row per question then try this:

```
select
  QuestionID,
  sum(case when Answer = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as CountA,
  sum(case when Answer = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as CountB,
  sum(case when Answer = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as CountC
from (
    select 'Question1' as QuestionID, Q1 as Answer from surveytable
    union all select 'Question2', Q2 from surveytable
    union all select 'Question3', Q3 from surveytable
    union all select 'Question4', Q4 from surveytable
    union all select 'Question5', Q5 from surveytable) x
group by QuestionID
```

There's a Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/649a1/2).

---

**Another Addendum**: Counts needed by `ID`, and because there's one `ID` per row there's no need for `SUM`.

This changes the approach. It first strings the answers together:

```
concat(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5) -- result for ID=1 in the test data: 'ABCAC'
```

... then it sucks every occurrence of `A` from the string:

```
replace(concat(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5), 'A', '') -- result for ID=1: 'BCC'
```

... the first string (`ABCAC`) is length `5`, and the second string (`BCC`) is length 3. The difference in length is the number of `A` answers: `2`. That's about as well as I can explain this. Now for the query:

```
select
  id,
  5 - length(replace(concat(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5), 'A', '')) AS CountA,
  5 - length(replace(concat(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5), 'B', '')) AS CountB,
  5 - length(replace(concat(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5), 'C', '')) AS CountC
from surveytable;
```

The updated Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/649a1/5).

This gives the raw data only. The formatting will be a bit tricky but it shouldn't be too bad, especially if you do it with a front-end language. If you must use MySQL for this, it will probably be easier to put the above into a subquery and apply the formatting in the outer query:

```
select
  id,
  CONCAT('You have chosen ' ...and miles of formatting logic using CountA, etc)
from (
  select
    id,
    5 - length(replace(concat(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5), 'A', '')) AS CountA,
    5 - length(replace(concat(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5), 'B', '')) AS CountB,
    5 - length(replace(concat(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5), 'C', '')) AS CountC
  from surveytable) x
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, this is looking interesting, but my table structure is actually more like this;  create table surveytable (id int, `Q1` char(1), `Q2` char(1),`Q3` char(1), `Q4` char(1), `Q5` char(1));

insert into surveytable values
 (1, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'),
 (2, 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'),
 (3, 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C');

Comment: @Carlos - your table structure was cut off from your comment. Sorry - ignore that - I see it now. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I'm new to stackoverflow and haven't got the hang of formatting yet.

Comment: It's getting there (and I've learned a lot already thanks), but all I really need is a result total for a particular row, so for example, when id=2 the result would be "You have chosen 'A' 3 times, 'B' once, and 'C' once". Basically get the total counts of 'A', 'B' and 'C' for the row where id=2. I'm not sure if this helps, but the survey is an online version similar to the ones you see in magazines, where, if you answer mostly A's you are sporty and if you answer mostly C's you are a couch potato!

Comment: This has been an interesting question @Carlos. I've updated the answer; look for the section starting with "Another Addendum".

Comment: Ingenious, that's it! Many thanks for your time and expertise Ed. As you say, it'll be easier to output the raw data with PHP, but I'll be comfortable with that. Now, go and get yourself a coffee, you've earned it!

Comment: I'm glad this worked out @Carlos! Like I said, it was an interesting question. Great idea about the coffee; I'm on my way :)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you could load the results of the query into an arary, and then use `array_count_values` to get the count of each answer:

```
$array = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $row;
}

// print_r(array_count_values($array); 

foreach(array_count_values($array) as $key => $value)
{
     echo 'Answer ' . $key . ' was chosen ' . $value . ' times <br>';
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/1en-6ci)

Comment: Hi Evan,How would I go about stuffing the values of the recordset (one complete row) into the array?

Comment: @Carlos You did this using the `while loop` as shown above. If that doesn't make sense I can try to make it more clear, but did you notice that part?

Comment: Ah, no I didn't notice, I was looking at the code on Fiddle... could you expand on it for me please (I'm used to ASP, and am new to PHP!)

Comment: @Carlos My code assumes that you have queried your database, and the `result` of the query is stored in the variable `$result`. From here, you want to `loop` through the result set, which is done in the line `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`. Each `$row` in the loop will contain an associate array containing the data from each row from your database.

Comment: @Carlos If everything is handled, please be sure to mark an answer as accepted to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: from memory so may not exactly work.

How about this?

SELECT 1 AS 1,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Questions WHERE 1 = 'A') AS A,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Questions WHERE 1 = 'B') AS B,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Questions WHERE 1 = 'C') AS C

Hope this helps.